# What would be the most idiomatic way of telling $10 discount when spending $98?Thanks

Tags: american-english

$10 discount when spending $98

### $30 discount when spending $198

Is that natural or idiomatic? or Is there a better way of telling this?
How about"  SAVE 10$ for OVER 98$ "?

Could anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to say this:

- Take $10 off your purchase over $98
- $10 off your next purchase over $98
- Get $10 off your purchase over $98
- Save $10 on your purchase over $98
- Save $10 on purchases over $98
- Get $10 when you spend $98 dollars or more
- Get $10 when you spend $98 dollars (implied that you spend at least $98)

These are common phrases you might hear from a retailer. They're usually ungrammatical in order to get to the point. They usually include "you" or "your" in them. I don't usually hear "discount" thrown in there. It is possible to use "discount":

> - $10 discount on purchases over $98
> - $10 discount when you spend $98

I am just saying that it is not common (in my experience). "When spending" doesn't sound right to me.

However, when you're having a conversation. It sounds fine to say something like

> I got a $10 discount when I spent $98 at store X.

Comment: :) Thank you very much for your reply. Very details~

Comment: "Very detailed". No problem, good luck!

Comment: ：） yup, very detailed.

Answer (score 0):

$10 off when spending $98 or more

$30 off when spending $198 or more

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.